# Who is slow in this traceroute result?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I am using Atlassian Jira Agile Cloud, but browsing is very slow. Nothing like Bitbucket. So I tried to traceroute to see if my ISP is slow or Attlassian (as I see many people complain on slowness, but they always reply it's our ISP fault). However, I am not sure how to interpret these results.

This is what my traceroute report looks like

```
traceroute -T MyServer.atlassian.net 2800

traceroute to MyServer.atlassian.net (131.103.xx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.141 ms  0.184 ms  0.227 ms
 2  * * *
 3  mo-he-m-1-pc2.xxx.com (77.77.xxx.xx)  19.949 ms  20.002 ms  20.057 ms
 4  10ge-6-2.ar2.lju.ip.xxx.net (213.xxx.xxx.169)  34.600 ms  34.657 ms  34.710 ms
 5  10ge-e6-2.vie.ip.xxx.net (213.xxx.xxx.142)  56.415 ms 10ge-e5-2.vie.ip.xxx.net (213.xxx.xxx.110)  56.447 ms  56.516 ms
 6  peer-AS31042.sbb.rs (82.117.193.193)  56.601 ms  28.937 ms  35.160 ms
 7  bg-tp-r-1-hu7-0.sbb.rs (89.216.5.250)  41.556 ms bg-ne-r-1-hu6-0.sbb.rs (89.216.5.254)  41.572 ms  41.627 ms
 8  lag-10.bear1.RepublicOfSerbia2.Level3.net (213.242.124.1)  46.439 ms  39.514 ms  46.487 ms
 9  * * *
10  ATLASSIN-IN.edge1.Washington1.Level3.net (4.35.233.190)  138.410 ms  142.830 ms  134.379 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  wildcard-proxy-104-1-atlnet.ash1.uc-inf.net (131.103.26.123)  139.773 ms  137.233 ms  133.969 ms
```

Or this is neither fault, but a jump from 46ms to 138ms is normal when packets go from Europe to USA?

Comment: A jump going across the pond is expected.  I would hazard that if many people are experiencing the problem then it is probably the hosting system.  Atlassian are probably just wanting to fend off those not willing to pursue the issue - personally I have always used self hosted for reasons of privacy and control, I appreciate its not for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

This traceroute result does not show any problems that would explain the issue you are having with your application. Your traceroute result is perfectly normal. Nobody is "slow".

The fastest fibre links from Europe to the US are around 60-80ms in latency, plus you have additional distance from the landing points to Washington and Serbia. This is again, perfectly normal.

A 138ms round trip time is fine for general web use. A fast web server should load in <1 second in those circumstances. Your problem is not with your latency or your traceroute.

Comment: Any idea where and how to pinpoint the slowdowns when using Jira Cloud? I am on pro i7, 16GB RAM machine, so machine is not an issue. Internet connection is 20mbps so I doubt it's an issue as well.

Comment: Use a web browser such as Chrome that will show you the precise timings of each request, and where it is being held up. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Answer (score 0):

well, 139.773ms at the speed of light is 
`0.139773 Light Seconds => 41,902.891232034 KM`, which is slightly more than the circumfrance of the earth (40,075.16 KM).

Per Google, the distance between Serbia and DC is about 8000 KM, so you could expect that in an absolutely perfect world where everything is fiber with infinite capacity and all routers work at line-speed, that it would take at least 26.6851276158522 MS, so there is some lag and drag if you are seeing 139 MS, but that also seems pretty reasonable for inter-continental connections.

Look at it this way, your internet connection is capable of pinging half way around the world at approximately 1/6th the speed of the fastest phenomona in the universe.

Comment: The real experience on Jira Cloud is much worse. I click and wait approx 4-5s for something to load. The new click, the same. Nothing similar have I faced on any similar service, not even on Attassian other services.

Comment: Firstly this does not answer the question. Secondly, data does not travel at the speed of light in fibre, even in a perfect world. Finally, the fastest transatlantic link in existence - which isn't even active yet - is 56ms coast-to-coast.

Comment: qasdfdsaq says 'data does not travel at the speed of light in fibre'. If that is the case, then what is traveling in the fiber and at what speed? In a perfect world the fiber would almost behave like a vacuum,  but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber, in our world, the speed of light in fiber is 200 000 km/sec, or 40 msec for 8000 km. I do think Frank Thomas more or less answers the question as he gives an indication of the physically fastest possible speed. Compared to 40 msec, one should understand that 139 msec is a very reasonable latency.